# Sum up "points" between time points over two tables

Tags: r, datetime, join

I have to data sets. One is called "yourdf" and contains a start time called "Start" and some other columns.
Lets assume the following data set for this.

```
yourdf <- data.frame (Start = c("2022-06-10 10:00:00", "2022-06-02 10:00:20", "2022-06-10 10:30:00", "2022-06-10 10:20:00", "2022-06-10 10:21:00"),
                    User = c("A", "A", "C", "A", "B"))
```

Then I have a second data sets with time points and "credits" or "points".

```
mydf <- data.frame (Timepoint = c("2022-06-10 10:00:03", "2022-06-02 10:00:20", "2022-06-10 10:30:00", "2022-06-10 10:20:00", "2022-06-10 10:21:00",
                             "2022-06-01 10:10:10", "2022-06-11 11:00:10", "2022-06-10 10:00:00", "2022-06-10 13:00:00", "2022-04-12 10:00:00",
                             "2022-06-09 10:00:00", "2022-06-10 10:00:00", "2022-06-10 10:11:20", "2022-06-10 10:00:05", "2022-06-04 10:00:00", "2022-06-10 10:11:12"),
                    Points = c("2", "4", "1", "5", "12",
                             "3", "2", "3", "2", "1",
                             "7", "2", "1", "0", "2", "1"))
```

**What I'm looking for: I want to sum up the credits of table mydf for specific time spans!**

**How I have to "aggregate" the data?** Let's work with the first time entry of table "yourdf". This one is "`2022-06-10 10:00:00`". I want to add a period of "10 minutes" on this. So I can add a column called "`End`"

This can be done by

```
yourdf["End"] <- as.POSIXct(yourdf$Start) + minutes(10)
```

*Note:* `yourdf$Start` has the class "character"

So we have a new table yourdf with a "Start" and a "End" date.

Now I want to sum up all "`points`" of table "`mydf`" between the "`Start`" and the "`End`" date of table yourdf

`Yourdf` looks like this

```
                Start User                 End
1 2022-06-10 10:00:00    A 2022-06-10 10:10:00
2 2022-06-02 10:00:20    A 2022-06-02 10:10:20
3 2022-06-10 10:30:00    C 2022-06-10 10:40:00
4 2022-06-10 10:20:00    A 2022-06-10 10:30:00
5 2022-06-10 10:21:00    B 2022-06-10 10:31:00
```

Let's look a line 1. Start time is "`2022-06-10 10:00:00`" and "`2022-06-10 10:10:00`".

So I want to generate a table like this one

```
                Start                  End      Points
1 2022-06-10 10:00:00  2022-06-10 10:10:00          7
2 2022-06-02 10:00:20  2022-06-02 10:10:20
3 2022-06-10 10:30:00  2022-06-10 10:40:00
4 2022-06-10 10:20:00  2022-06-10 10:30:00
5 2022-06-10 10:21:00  2022-06-10 10:31:00
```

because just the entries

```
1  2022-06-10 10:00:03      2
8  2022-06-10 10:00:00      3
12 2022-06-10 10:00:00      2
14 2022-06-10 10:00:05      0
```

of table "`mydf`" are between the "`Start`" and the "`End`" point.

How can I achieve this with Project R for large tables with thousands of entries?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
# set to data.table format
setDT(yourdf); setDT(mydf)
# set to posix timestamp
yourdf[, Start := as.POSIXct(Start)]
mydf[, Timepoint := as.POSIXct(Timepoint)]
# create a unique rowwise key for yourdf
yourdf[, id := .I][]
setkey(yourdf, id)
# loop over each row/key in yourdf (by = .EACHI),
# subset mydf based on Start + 10 minutes, and sum Points
yourdf[yourdf, .(Start, 
                 End = Start + 600,
                 Points = mydf[Timepoint %between% c(Start, Start + 600), 
                               sum(as.numeric(Points))]), 
       by = .EACHI][]
#    id               Start                 End Points
# 1:  1 2022-06-10 10:00:00 2022-06-10 10:10:00      7
# 2:  2 2022-06-02 10:00:20 2022-06-02 10:10:20      4
# 3:  3 2022-06-10 10:30:00 2022-06-10 10:40:00      1
# 4:  4 2022-06-10 10:20:00 2022-06-10 10:30:00     18
# 5:  5 2022-06-10 10:21:00 2022-06-10 10:31:00     13
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Wimpel... I'm working on a Mac and I get the following message after loading the package "data.table"

Comment: data.table 1.14.2 using 1 threads (see ?getDTthreads).  Latest news: r-datatable.com
**********
This installation of data.table has not detected OpenMP support. It should still work but in single-threaded mode.
This is a Mac. Please read https://mac.r-project.org/openmp/. Please engage with Apple and ask them for support. Check r-datatable.com for updates, and our Mac instructions here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation. After several years of many reports of installation problems on Mac,

Comment: it's time to gingerly point out that there have been no similar problems on Windows or Linux.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot... Just a further question: You are working with a subset in the last line... Why? How can I work with the full set?

Comment: regarding your last question: the solution loops over each row (`.EACHI`) of yourdf. Based on the current row's value of `yourdf$Start`, it creates a temporary subset of mydf-rows that match the logical conditions, and them sums `Points` of this subset. Then repeat for each row in `yourdf`.

Comment: Thanks @Wimpel Does it mean I can't work with a larger table because I can just work with a subset including the relevant columns?

Comment: not sure what you mean by that. The solution above uses your whole yourdf, and whole mydf to get the answer.

Comment: That's right and sorry for the confusion. I guess I'm not familiar with "yourdf[yourdf, .(...". So my question is how I can add more columns? For example  a time period Start+10 minutes (as you already mention) AND (!) Start-10minutes. So can I loop twice to obtain several time periods in one "solution"?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter `mydf` with `between()` function and find the summation the points. Looping this through the rows of `yourdf` could be done to find the points for all the time periods.

```
library(lubridate)

yourdf$Start <- as.POSIXct(yourdf$Start)


yourdf$End <- yourdf$Start + minutes(10)

mydf$Timepoint <- as.POSIXct(mydf$Timepoint)

yourdf$Points <- unlist(apply(yourdf[,-2], 1, function(x) mydf %>% 
                                      filter(between(Timepoint, as.POSIXct(x["Start"]), as.POSIXct(x["End"]))) %>% 
                                      mutate(Points = as.numeric(Points)) %>% 
                                      summarise(Total_Points = sum(Points)),
                                    simplify = T))
```

Output:

```
> yourdf
                Start User                 End       Points
1 2022-06-10 10:00:00    A 2022-06-10 10:10:00            7
2 2022-06-02 10:00:20    A 2022-06-02 10:10:20            4
3 2022-06-10 10:30:00    C 2022-06-10 10:40:00            1
4 2022-06-10 10:20:00    A 2022-06-10 10:30:00           18
5 2022-06-10 10:21:00    B 2022-06-10 10:31:00           13
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mohanasundaram.... This one looks really great. Just a short question: In the last line you work with the unlist and apply function... I'm not familiar with the term "yourdf[,-2]". Yes, yourdf is my data.frame. The [] indicate a selection and you are excluding column 2, right... So yourdf[,-2] is the same like yourdf[,1], right?

Comment: `yourdf[,-2]` excludes column 2 retaining all other columns, while yourdf[, 1] retains the first column alone, excluding all other columns. The choice is up to you whether you want to retain other columns or not.

Comment: Thanks @Mohanasundaram .... Your totally right! Nearly forgot that "-2" just exclude  column 2. To achieve some more exclusions I can work with "-c(1,3:4,6)" for example, right?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant way, but

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  apply(yourdf,1,function(x){
    data.frame(
      "Start"=x["Start"],
      "End"=x["End"],
      "Points"=sum(
        as.numeric(
          mydf[
            as.POSIXct(mydf$Timepoint)>=as.POSIXct(x["Start"]) &
            as.POSIXct(mydf$Timepoint)<as.POSIXct(x["End"]),
            "Points"
          ]
        )
      )
    )
  })
)

                     Start                 End Points
Start  2022-06-10 10:00:00 2022-06-10 10:10:00      7
Start1 2022-06-02 10:00:20 2022-06-02 10:10:20      4
Start2 2022-06-10 10:30:00 2022-06-10 10:40:00      1
Start3 2022-06-10 10:20:00 2022-06-10 10:30:00     17
Start4 2022-06-10 10:21:00 2022-06-10 10:31:00     13
```